# Populating property of type Dictionary<> items from within razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Is there a way to pass values to a property of type Dictionary<> from within a view using Html.BeginForm helper method?

Model

```
public class LogicTest
{
    public int LogicTestID { get; set; }
    public string SingleString { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SimpleDictionary { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> NestedDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

ATM I'm trying something like this (obviously without much success)

```
@model TestNamespace.Models.LogicTest

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateLogicTest", "LogicTest"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(n => n.SingleString)<br />
    @Html.EditorFor(n => n.SingleString)<br />

    @Html.LabelFor(n => n.SimpleDictionary)<br />

    @Html.Label("Simple Dictionary Item 1")
    @Html.EditorFor(n => n.SimpleDictionary["key1"])
    @Html.Label("Simple Dictionary Item 2")
    @Html.EditorFor(n => n.SimpleDictionary["key2"])
    @Html.Label("Simple Dictionary Item 3")
    @Html.EditorFor(n => n.SimpleDictionary["key3"])

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of your class within your controller action. Then return a view with that class.